# BitmapEncoder SetPixelData memory allocation

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-async

I'm working on a Metro application where I need to generate an animated GIF image.

I've found [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/02/28/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-with-winrt.aspx), witch seems to be the one and only resource on animated GIFs for Metro apps.

When running this code, an Exception is thrown on the SetPixelData method, telling me that **the allocated buffer memory** is insufficient (The message is in my OS language even though my Visual Studio environnement is in English, I think it might be relevant).

I've reduced image size (source and output) and frame number, but I still get this error. (I manipulate way bigger images and byte array in the same application).

Any idea where this memory problem can come from ? A problem with my StorageFile maybe ?

Comment: I have the same issue and I have no idea what buffer is insufficient.  I'm trying to write to a file.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing this exception when the frameWidth\Height being passed into SetPixelData didn't match the pixel data.

I ended up with this example below. I was seeing the exception you mentioned when the dimensions didn't match the pixelData.

I think this is more stable in Windows 8.1 as it doesn't repro on it.

```
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceStream);
                BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform()
                {
                    ScaledHeight = 900,
                    ScaledWidth = 600
                };
                PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8,
                                                                              BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                                                                              transform,
                                                                              ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
                                                                              ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

                StorageFile destinationFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Path.Combine(Database.rootMoviesFoldersPaths, movie.LocalId + ".jpg"));
                using (var destinationStream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, destinationStream);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, 600, 900, 96, 96, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();

                    movie.HasFolderImage = true;

                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiply the buffersize by the bitdepth.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I don't see which buffersize should be multiplied. I not very familiar with memory manipulation in .NET.

Comment: Say for example, you have a 100x100 image.  Say that each pixel of this image can have 16 shades of gray.  How much space do you need to store this image?  100x100x16